# HTML: How to cross check HTML Check Box

Tags: html

Is it possiible to cross check HTML checkbox?

Thanks
Sohail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to change the way a checkbox looks when it is checked.

That is not possible using HTML's native `<input type="checkbox">` controls: They are rendered by the browser, and usually in the style the Operating System renders check boxes.

You would have to use a JavaScript checkbox component that allows you to use custom bitmaps. One example is the [jQuery checkbox plugin](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/).

Whether adding all this code for this minimal effect is worth the effort, you need to decide for yourself. In my opinion, it is usually not worth it and sticking to the normal controls is better.

Answer (score 1):

While standard checkbox look [could be personalized](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) you might need to [implement a custom checkbox](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/customized_html_controls_creating_custom_checkbox.aspx) to achieve the desired effect.